# Rearranging string letters

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I was doing a program to **copy all string words other than its first 2 words and putting a x at the end of it.**
However i cant put x at its end. Please help!!!!
Below is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[25], b[25];
    int i, j, count = 0, l, k;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
    i = strlen(a);
    if (i > 20)
        printf("Given Sentence is too long.");
    else
    {/* checking for first 2 words and counting 2 spaces*/
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] == ' ')
                count = count + 1;
            if (count == 2)
            {
                k = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* copying remaining string into new one*/
        for (j = 0; j < i - k; j++)
        {
            b[j] = a[j + k];
        }
        b[j + 1] = 'x';
        printf("%s", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to append an extra char at the end like that, you will overwrite the NUL terminator and so shoud 'manually' append another NUL.

Comment: why are u downvoting it

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", a)` is wrong. Use: `scanf("%24[^\n]", a)` or `scanf("%24s", a)`; don't mix `[...]` and `s`

Comment: @Kiko not my downvote, but it's probably because there are countless similar questions about "strings" not correctly terminated, using `scanf()` on strings without field widths, missing a correct array index etc. You should try to solve simple problems yourself, here's an article that might help you in the future: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Kiko note that the answer you accepted will leave your program **undefined**. Without either initializing your `b` or explicitly adding a terminating `0`, you're not constructing a string, it just **might** work because there already were `0` values in the array by accident.

Comment: I did not downvote it either, just posted a comment.  For some reason, your 'why are u downvoting it' comment above appeared in my inbox?

Comment: @MartinJames because it directly follows your comment.

Comment: @FelixPalmen ah.. it's an automated thingy.  OK:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C strings are array of chars as you know and the way C knows it is end of the string is '\0' character. In your example you are missing at the last few lines

```
/* copying remaining string into new one*/
 for(j=0;j<i-k;j++)
 {
     b[j]=a[j+k];
 }
 b[j+1]='x';
 printf("%s",b);
```

after the loop ends j is already increased 1 before it quits the loop.

So if your string before x is "test", it is like 
't', 'e', 's', 't','\0' in char array, and since your j is increased more than it should have, it gets to the point just right of '\0', but characters after '\0' doesnt matter, because it is the end, so your x will not be added. Simple change to

```
b[j]='x';
```

Comment: And this is still wrong because `b` is an uninitialized variable of automatic storage duration, so there's no guarantee it holds `0` values. This would just work *by accident*.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is off by one. After your second loop, the condition `j < i-k` was false, so `j` now **is** `i-k`. Therefore, the character after the end of what you copied is `b[j]`, not `b[j+1]`. The correct line would therefore be `b[j] = 'x';`.

Just changing this would leave you with something that is **not** a *string*. A *string* is defined as a sequence of `char`, ending with a `'\0'` char. So you **have** to add `b[j+1] = 0;` as well.

After these changes, your code does what you intended, but still has undefined behavior.

---

One problem is that your `scanf()` will happily overflow your buffer -- use a **field width** here: `scanf("%24[^\n]", a);`. And by the way, the `s` at the and doesn't make any sense, you use **either** the `s` conversion **or** the `[]` conversion.

---

A somewhat sensible implementation would use functions suited for the job, like e.g. this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // memory is *cheap* nowadays, these buffers are still somewhat tiny:
    char a[256];
    char b[256];

    // read a line
    if (!fgets(a, 256, stdin)) return 1;
    // and strip the newline character if present
    a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = 0;

    // find first space
    char *space = strchr(a, ' ');

    // find second space
    if (space) space = strchr(space+1, ' ');

    if (space)
    {
        // have two spaces, copy the rest
        strcpy(b, space+1);
        // and append 'x':
        strcat(b, "x");
    }
    else
    {
        // empty string:
        b[0] = 0;
    }

    printf("%s",b);
    return 0;
}
```

For functions you don't know, google for `man <function>`.

Answer (score 0):

you are removing first two index. But you wrote k=j and if you check the current value j there it's 1. so you are updating wrongly k because you removed 2 indexes. So k value should be 2. So checked the below code

```
/* copying remaining string into new one*/
        for (j = 0; j < i - 2; j++)
        {
            b[j] = a[j + 2];
        }
        b[j + 1] = 'x';
        printf("%s", b);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.